# How to be able to check the input data is the same from previous input data?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have an assignment which provides a dataset. I created a struct array and want to input the values but do not know how to input the value without having it repeat in the same array.

For example, there are 18 women in the dataset with the respective events that they attended to.

e.g

```
Tiffany, E1
Tiffany, E2
Tiffany, E3
Tiffany, E4
Tiffany, E5
Tiffany, E6
Tiffany, E8
Tiffany, E9
Dione, E1
Dione, E2
Dione, E3
Dione, E5
Dione, E6
Dione, E7
Dione, E8
Kelly, E2
Kelly, E3
Kelly, E4
Kelly, E5
Kelly, E6
Kelly, E7
Kelly, E8
Kelly, E9
```

What kind of codes can I use so that when I input the dataset, the first struct array is allocated to Tiffany and her respective events E1, E2, E3 etc and the 2nd struct will have Dione and her events that she attended. In the dataset, different women has attended different number of events. I would like to know if it is able to check if the first input which is the first name is the same or not in order to create a new array if it is another woman.

Comment: Can you read the dataset from file and load into your structure? Alternariverly, can you regenerate it at runtime?

Comment: I have not loaded the dataset yet into the structure because I am still finding the code to check that the first womans event is in the array before creating a new array for the next woman and her events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use STL it's as simple as iterating through the array and after finding each person changing it's event. Bellow you can see a pseudo-code:

```
string prevName="", currName;

//read currName and event from the file
if (prevName != currName){
    //create a new entry in the array
    prevName = currName;
}
//add event in the current array position
```

But you can also use STL in the following way:

```
//These header are needed
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//this is an example of defining persons and events
string p = "Tiffany", e = "E1";

//this is our data structure to keep records of people
map<string, vector<string> > PersonEvent;
//updating is as simple as calling this function
PersonEvent[p].push_back(e);

//going through every record of a person
for(int i=0; i<PersonEvent[p].size(); i++)
   //do something with PersonEvent[p][i]
```

Comment: If using struct arrays, how is it able to input data into the array? Like how can I code in such a way that I can check if the input is no longer Tiffany but Dione to create a new struct array?

-edit- I'll add it to my question to make it more clear

Comment: I've updated my answer. Add a part of your code if you need more details so I would be able to explain more.

Comment: I understood the code that you included, thank you.
This is the code that I'm stuck with. Which is the storing part.

`code`struct Person
{
 string name;
 string event[];
};
Person P[];

while (input>>ws && !input.eof()){
                if(PrevName== CurrentName)
  input >> P.name;
                input >>P.event;

               else
               person * P = new P[SIZE];
 }